# Find a quartic (degree 4) polynomial with integer coefficients whose roots are the primitive 12th roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find a quartic (degree 4) polynomial with integer coefficients whose roots are the primitive 12th roots of unity

How to even approach this?

Comment: The polynomial $(z-\alpha_1) (z-\alpha_2) \cdots (z-\alpha_n)$ has roots $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_n$.

Comment: Minimal polynomials of this from have a name: they are [cyclotomic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Answer (score 3):

First we find the primitive $12$-th roots of unity. These will be in the form 
$e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{12}}=e^{\frac{\pi i k}{6}}$
for $0\le k<12$, where $\gcd(k,12)=1$. With these restrictions, there are $4$ such $k$s: $1$, $5$, $7$, $11$.

Now all we have to do is compute the polynomial 
$$P=\left(x-e^{\frac{\pi i}{6}}\right)\left(x-e^{\frac{5\pi i}{6}}\right)\left(x-e^{\frac{7\pi i}{6}}\right)\left(x-e^{\frac{11\pi i}{6}}\right)$$
To do this nicely, we pair up complex conjugates and expand:

$\begin{align}
P&=\left(x-e^{\frac{\pi i}{6}}\right)\left(x-e^{\frac{5\pi i}{6}}\right)\left(x-e^{\frac{7\pi i}{6}}\right)\left(x-e^{\frac{11\pi i}{6}}\right)
\\&=\left(x-e^{\frac{\pi i}{6}}\right)\left(x-e^{\frac{11\pi i}{6}}\right)\left(x-e^{\frac{5\pi i}{6}}\right)\left(x-e^{\frac{7\pi i}{6}}\right)
\\&=\left(x^2-\left(e^{\frac{\pi i}{6}}+e^{\frac{11\pi i}{6}}\right)x+e^{2\pi i}\right)\left(x^2-\left(e^{\frac{5\pi i}{6}}+e^{\frac{7\pi i}{6}}\right)x+e^{2\pi i}\right)
\\&=\left(x^2-\sqrt{3}x+1\right)\left(x^2+\sqrt{3}x+1\right)
\\&=x^4-x^2+1
\end{align}$